# Run Laravel 5 seeder programmatically instead of from CLI

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to run the Laravel 5 seeder from within PHP rather than from the command line. The hosting I am using doesn't allow me to use the command line. Just to confirm I want to do the equivalent of this but in my app code:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
Artisan::call('db:seed');
```

To get the output of the last run command, you can use:

```
Artisan::output();
```

Comment: Related: How do you call this for a specific class?  For example, if you want to call the equivalent of `php artisan db:seed --class=User`?  I see that you pass an array to the `Artisan::call()` function, but I get an invalid argument exception when I use `Artisan::call('db:seed', ['class'=>'Users'])` saying "The 'class' argument does not exist."

Comment: Artisan::call('command:name', array('argument' => 'foo', '--option' => 'bar'));

See https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands#calling-other-commands

Comment: The answer below is a much better option

Comment: @Kirkland, If you want to run specific seeder Class, try `Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'YourSeederClass']);`

Answer (score 35):

You can also call directly the Seeder class if needed. 
Just make sure you did a composer dump-autoload if you created your seeder manually.

From there code is very straightforward :

```
$seeder = new YourSeederClass();
$seeder->run();
```

Comment: To do it in 1 line:
(new MySeeder)->run();

Comment: Use `$this->call(MySeeder:.class)` is running from inside another Seeder

Answer (score 8):

You can add parameters to the seeder on run

example

```
  $newSchool = School::create($data);

     $schoolMeals = new \MealSeeder();
     $schoolMeals->run($newSchool->id);
```

//school meal

```
 public function run($school = 1)
    {

        $time = Carbon::now();

        App\Meal::create([
            'school_id' => $school,
            'name' => 'Breakfast',
            'slug' => 'breakfast',
            'description' => 'Test Meal',
            'start_time' => $time->toTimeString(),
            'end_time' => $time->addMinutes(60)->toTimeString(),
        ]);
        App\Meal::create([
            'school_id' => $school,
            'name' => 'Lunch',
            'slug' => 'lunch',
            'description' => 'Test Meal',
            'start_time' => $time->toTimeString(),
            'end_time' => $time->addMinutes(60)->toTimeString(),
        ]);
        App\Meal::create([
            'school_id' => $school,
            'name' => 'Supper',
            'slug' => 'supper',
            'description' => 'Test Meal',
            'start_time' => $time->toTimeString(),
            'end_time' => $time->addMinutes(60)->toTimeString(),
        ]);
    }
```